# Any trick to backup non-Xbox games data

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, backup, nokia-lumia-1020, games, xbox-live

Most of the Xbox-labeled games has a pretty decent way to backup their data (or at least the game progress). On the other hand those who don't have any Xbox label lack of this kind of feature (e.g. Star Wars: Tiny Death Star).

Do you guys know any trick to backup the game progress of this kind of games. I have been playing for about 4 months and tomorrow I have to change my handset so if I don't backup the game, all the progress will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to backup your game or app data (as of Windows Phone 8 Update 3).

According the [official documentation](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/back-up-my-stuff), only the following is backed up (if enabled in Settings > Backup)

- The list of apps you've installed on your phone.
- Your call history.
- Your theme colour.
- The accounts you've set up on your phone.
- Your Internet Explorer favourites.
- Settings from around your phone, including photos, messaging, email and accounts, location, Internet Explorer, lock screen, Speech and more.

I would recommend voting on [expanding the current backup feature to include app data](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3387112-expand-device-backup-scope-on-wp8).